# Determine the location List or Document Library

Tags: list, development

How can I determine if I'm in the List or Document library and I'm not on some page that is inside the document library?

For example if im on the page which is located in the pages and I do:

```
SPContext.Current.List
```

I will get a list Pages. So how can I determine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a SPContext.Current.ListItem and the url of that is the same as the url of the Page (without query parameters), then you're on a page inside a document library.

If not and you have a SPContext.Current.List then you're on a list or on a list item

Comment: hmm, but is there a more proper way to determine where i'm located?

Comment: I think solution given by Per is the most proper way to achieve this, if you need to distinguish between which type of list (i.e generic list, doc lib, discussion board) then use BaseType property of list which returns SPBaseType enum